# IIS sends js and css files with Mime text/html but only for SOME not all

Tags: iis, iis-7, resources, mime-types, content-type

A handful of js and css files are not being loaded by the webpage (404 not found) because the mime type is coming back as text/html instead of text/css or application/x-javascript:

[image]

I have tried changing my .htaccess file to the following:

```
AddType text/x-component .htc
AddType text/css .css
AddType application/x-javascript .js
```

The resources that load versus the ones that do not are written in exactly the same way.  This one is working:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This one is not working:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-ui-1.11.0.custom/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have also tried editing the regedit entry for js to include the content type and perceived type:

[image]

I have also tried to add the following in my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
         <remove fileExtension=".js" />
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="application/x-javascript" />
         <remove fileExtension=".css" />
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".css" mimeType="text/css" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Same permissions are also set on all these files.  At this point, I know it has to be some configuration on the server because I have this exact same version of the code deployed on a different server with no issues...any ideas?

Comment: You sure it's a mime type problem? Go to www.google.com/asdf.css and it has a mime-type of text/html too...I think that's just what IE displays if it doesn't otherwise know.

Comment: You have a point there...it's just that when I look at the 7 out of 20 or so resources that won't load, they are of type text/html whereas the ones that do load are text/css and application/x-javascript...